# Android app can't connect to Socket.io server

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm making a basic real-time chat app with `Socket.io` in `Node.js`.

I created a server and the app, but it seems the app is not connecting to the server.

Here is my code I tried:

server.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port=8080;


app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
 res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  io.emit('msg','joined');
socket.on('msg', (msg) => {
    io.emit('msg', msg);
        console.log(msg);
  });

});


http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening: '+port);
});
```

client  java code:

```
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
...



String server="http://0.0.0.0:8080/";
private Socket sock;

    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
   
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try{
    sock=IO.socket(server);
   }catch(URISyntaxException e){}
        
        sock.connect();
        if(sock.connected()){
            toast("Connected");
        }else{
            toast("Not connected");
        }

//always showing not connected

}
```

so when I open the app, it shows 'Not connected' as this will be executed only if the app couldn't connect to the server.

logCat keeps adding only this line multiple times:
 `(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false`

**Note:**
I'm hosting Node.js on my android device with termux.(it works fine on the browser). Also the same android device I used to create the app with the Android IDE app.

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: i tried 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0 and also localhost but none of them worked 

Comment: Websocket doesn't use http, try change to ws://0.0.0.0:8080